# Facebook Authentication failed in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.5 in android ,  when I tried log in button,the permission message appear I accept and  it just returned to log in screen

```
  authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email"));
authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (session.isOpened()) {
              Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                      new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                              if (user != null) { 
                               Log.i(TAG,"User ID "+ user.getId());
                               Log.i(TAG,"Email "+ user.asMap().get("email"));
                               lblEmail.setText(user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                              }
                          }
                      });} } });
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }


}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, it seems I was unable to even get the samples to work, they were also having the same issue. I had thought it had to do with the importing of the SDK or android-support-v4 but that wouldn't make sense why the samples don't work either. Getting !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: 1- for the android-support-v4 : when you import Facebook SDK it containts android-sup-v4 , and your project containts it also , so you will have two jars in the same project , Delete one in the lib folder 
2- For the example , you should  add your hadh key to Facebook developpers site in order to be able to work with samples 
3 - check this site it's very useful http://www.happycodingwithdjo.com/category/api/facebook-sdk-android/